# making a single prediction based on multiple predictions with associated uncertainties (eg ensemble models)

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, error-propagation

Let's say I have a set of predictions $y_i$ and associated uncertainties $\sigma_i$ and the predictions are all normally distributed. How can I "add" these up to make some final prediction. ie predictions with low uncertainty are more trustworthy etc...

Comment: If you add multiple uncertain events... the result will be even more uncertain. I think you are looking for something other than "add".

Comment: yep apologies, I meant more along the lines of if you have N models that make a prediction, and these return N uncertainties. If 1 model had uncertainty 0 you would just pick that one for example. But realistically none have 0 uncertainty, what theory do you use to best combine the predictions to get the most "accurate" result in terms of minimizing uncertainty while not completely ignoring the other models results.

Comment: I suppose what I wrote only makes sense when you cannot perfectly trust the reported uncertainty of a specific model.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is just a simple average of all the predictions, you could use the uncertainties as weights in the calculation.

Comment: yep that's what I am currently doing, was just wondering if there is anything more statistically correct.

Comment: Lugosi discusses a *median of means* approach to Gaussian and sub-Gaussian processes in this paper *Mean estimation and regression under heavy-tailed distributions--a survey* https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04280